# Linear mapping: Find a matrix T with respect to the basis

Tags: linear-transformations

I've got this question:

"Consider a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$T(x,y,z)=(x+z,y-2z,x+y+z)$$

Find the matrix of T with respect to the basis $B=${$(1,0,-1),(1,1,1),(0,1,1)$} of $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is find $[T]_{B,B}$."

My first idea was just inserting the basis $B$ into $T(x,y,z)$. But then I could see it looks wrong. How should I attempt this problem?

Comment: Well is this true that $T_{[B,B]}$
$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2&2&0\\0&-1&3
\\-1&-1&2\end {array} \right] $

Comment: Sorry, should it be $\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2&0&-1\\2&-1&-1 \\0&3&2\end {array} \right]$

Comment: Are you sure one of those matrices is the answer?  For a start, we need $B$ as an **ordered** basis, not a set. Taking the order as the order listed (i.e. $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, I get $[T]_{B,B}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-4&-3\\-2&6&4\\4&-7&-5\end{bmatrix}$ by composing the change-of-basis from $B$ to standard, the matrix for $T$ (WRT to the standard basis), and the change-of-basis from standard back to $B$.

Comment: Yea I did a mistake, so I get the same as you